# Automator service to extract file and delete parent

Tags: finder, automator, bash, filesystem

I am trying to create an automator service to take the selected folders in Finder and search each of them for movie files, move those movie files to a certain directory and then move the original folder to trash. However I have no experience and keep getting stuck!

Up the top of the automator window I have selected this:

[image: my service so far]

I then thought the best thing to do would be to use the "Get Folder Contents" action and run some sort of bash script on each file.

But what would I put in the script? I don't know how to write bash scripts. I was thinking something along the lines of:

for each directory
for each file in the directory
if the file is a movie
move the file to this directory "path"
move the parent directory to trash

I don't know if I should select "Pass input as arguments" or "as stdin". Either way I don't know how to work with them.

Can anyone give me a bit of help with this script?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution I was looking for here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20120417192148/https://www.macworld.com/article/1160660/automator_filesfromsubfolders.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer your question. Please keep in mind that answers on AskDifferent should be more than just a link (because links can break rendering your answer useless). Including a link for reference is ok but please also summarize the solution directly in your answer.